# Can I lose data that is being written to the database during a cron jib backup?

Tags: database, cron, backup

I am setting up a Cron Job that will run every 15 minutes and if there is new data in a particular table it will back up that table, email it and delete it.

Do I have to be concerned that data will be written to the database at the same time as the backup is running and it will backup "half" the data and than delete the rest of it?

Comment: It all depends on exactly what the cron job does.

Comment: The Cron Job is Zipping up all the rows on the table (the one that I am concerned info is being written to simultaneously) and than deleted all the rows of the table

Answer (score 0):

If your job operates as you have described, there is a risk that new data could be added to the table after the `SELECT` used to generate the email but before the `DELETE`.

The simplest way to prevent this might be to run the two statements inside a transaction, assuming the database engine you're using supports transactions.

Alternatively, some database engines support returning data from a `DELETE` statement in a single atomic transaction - Postgres being one, with [the `RETURNING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-delete.html).

If that option isn't available to you, another solution would be to drive the `DELETE` using a high-water date/time or auto-incrementing identity column in the source table. 
Implementing this might require a schema change to your source table.
Pseudo-code would be something like:

```
SELECT <variable> = max(<identity>)
FROM   source_table

SELECT <columns>
FROM   source_table
WHERE  <identity> <= <variable>

DELETE source_table
WHERE  <identity> <= <variable>
```

Any data added to `source_table` between the first `SELECT` and the `DELETE` will have a higher identity value than is stored in `<variable>`, so will not be removed.